# rails faye doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I installed faye-rails gem, thin gem, put to config.ru

```
require 'faye'
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye')
run faye_server
```

then I run `rails s` but when client subscribtion script runs there is a routing error.
Maybe I should run one thins server for faye, and one for rails?

```
rails s
rackup config.ru -s thin -E production
```

Also one more question is it possible to use faye's thin with unicorn? Is it also should run as separate servers? as:

Comment: Error and full backtrace requires.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51289129/714985 you can find a complete description how set up Faye on Ununtu

Answer (score 1):

I am using **thin web-server** for my application to show notification.
 Maybe this is help full for you.
[Detail of using faye server in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567167/how-can-i-push-to-faye-server-from-rails-controller/33567635#33567635)